# Cannot find module that is npm linked in angular-cli app

Tags: angular, npm, module, webpack, angular-cli

I've forked an npm module and I'm doing local development on it. I have an angular-cli based app that is using this module via [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link). I'm importing this module into my app.module using a standard TypeScript import statement, however when I serve the app using "ng serve" I get "Cannot find module" errors for the linked module.

I've found some solutions online that discuss [changing webpack config settings](http://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#npm-linked-modules-doesn-t-find-their-dependencies) (which angular-cli doesn't seem to allow) and also what looked like a [fix already made](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1875). However, I still can't get this to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Am I perhaps doing the import the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems it is still open https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3875

Comment: @budkin, you got this working??